# Swinging/Bobbing Camera

Tags: c++, opengl

I have been searching on the internet for a while now, for a solution with nothing. What I want to know is how to implement a swing/bobbing motion in a 3D Camera in OpenGL(or DirectX) like you find in Minecraft, Call of Duty, etc. I tried cycloids, while they work I can't get the direction to work correctly.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

What do you think about the following.

1. compute `cam_pos`, `cam_dest`, `cam_up` as usual.
2. compute `cam_right` as cross (`cam_pos`, `cam_up`)
3. create a float `camera_time` (if walking, `camera_time += delta_time;` )
4. compute `offset_factor = sin(camera_time);`

Then you can call `gluLookAt` or similar function as follows.

```
gluLookAt(cam_pos + cam_right * offset_factor, cam_des + cam_right * offset_factort, cam_up)
```

This will make the camera swing from right to left. You can add the same for the `cam_up` vector with some tweaking.

Comment: That doesn't seem to be working for me... It is reversing my direction and different wierd effects.